# ExtJS form with array names

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, extjs4

I wont build a User Contact Form, with 2 tabs containing the same fields but on different language. Using MVC and ExtJS 4.0.7.

I wont to reuse the **userinfo** panel .. and just give it a paramether **langKey** = en/fr

The tab widget with user information looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.user.FormUserInfo', {
     extend: 'Ext.Panel',
     alias: 'widget.userinfo', 
     defaultType: 'textfield',

     items: [
     { 
         name: 'first_name['+langKey+']',
     }, {
         name: 'last_name['+langKey+']',  
     }]
 });
```

And the form loads it like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.user.Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.FormPanel',
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',  
        activeTab: 2,
        items:[
        {
            xtype: 'userinfo',
            cls: 'en',
            tabConfig: {
                title: 'Contact Details(EN)'
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'userinfo',
            cls: 'de',
            tabConfig: {
                title: 'Contact Details(DE)'
            } 
        }]// /TabPanel.items
    }]// /FormPanel.items
});
```

In fact the form contains 10+ fields and **2 or more** languages ..so I need a good control over the data.

Any way to pass a variable when using the widget or a property that I can use ?
i tried to use the panel class (**cls**)  `'first_name['+this.cls+']'` but the scope is wrong or something (and is a bit ugly).

Comment: Localization in Ext JS: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/localization

Comment: I don't need to translate the view, I need to add some flags on the field names and separate the information later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to add a custom config property to your user info panel, and then apply the custom config value to the field names within initComponent().

Example:

```
Ext.define('UserInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userinfo', 
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    langKey: 'en',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            items: [
             { 
                 fieldLabel: 'First Name '+me.langKey,
                 name: 'first_name['+me.langKey+']',
             }, {
                 fieldLabel: 'Last Name '+me.langKey,
                 name: 'last_name['+me.langKey+']',  
             }]            
        });
        me.callParent( arguments );
    }

});
```

You can then pass through the custom config, just like you would with any other:

```
{
    xtype: 'userinfo',
    lankKey: 'en',
    tabConfig: {
        title: 'Contact Details(EN)'
    }
}
```

[Here's a live example of it.](http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/58KKk/)

Comment: thanks a lot man! it is working perfect! and you gived me few ideas for refactoring  :)